# Ksoap2-android: How to tell ksoap2 to use an inner tag?

Tags: android, xml, soap

I have the following SOAP request (taken from SoapUI):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.mycompany.com" xmlns:xsd="http://types.mycompany.com/xsd">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <ser:entitlementSearch>
     <ser:request>
        <xsd:entitlementId>testdata</xsd:entitlementId>
    </ser:request>
  </ser:entitlementSearch>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The problem is that when I use ksoap2 on android it creates the mentioned request but without the ser:request tag. The android ksoap2 makes it look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.mycompany.com" xmlns:xsd="http://types.mycompany.com/xsd">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <ser:entitlementSearch>
    <xsd:entitlementId>testdata</xsd:entitlementId>
  </ser:entitlementSearch>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As you can see, the ser:request is missing there (the entitlementId is embedded directly in entitlementSearch) and therefore my web service does not get the input data in correct format.

Is there a way in ksoap2 how to overcome this problem? How can I tell ksoap2 to use the missing  tag?

Thank you,
krompo